# Multiple seperate objects constructed from same class

Tags: java

Beginner java programmer

I created a class Car

```
public class Car {

  private static final double MILES_PER_YEAR = 20000;
  private static final double GAS_PRICE =  2.50;

  private static double pricePerYear;
  private static double totalPrice;

  public Car(double initialPrice, double milesPerGallon) {
    pricePerYear = (MILES_PER_YEAR / milesPerGallon);
    totalPrice = initialPrice;
}
```

Then in my main function I construct two Car objects

```
Car civic = new Car(22000, 35.5);
Car prius = new Car(27135, 55.5);
```

However, when I check attributes of these objects with civic.getTotalPrice() and prius.getTotalPrice() they're always the same.  The second object contruction always overrides the first and when I construct them like I did above ^^ and get both prices, they both return 27135.  This happens the same way vice versa if I define them like this

```
Car prius = new Car(27135, 55.5);    
Car civic = new Car(22000, 35.5);
```

For the segment above, the return for both civic.getTotalPrice() and prius.getTotalPrice() comes out as 22000

I think the issue has something to do with keywords like public, private, static, void, final, etc. as I do not full yunderstand what they mean yes, but I'm confused as to why the code still runs if it is a keyword problem like that.

My main goal is to compare the seperate objects' attributes and modify them individually if that helps anyone understand where I was going with this.

Answer (score 1):

Make the member variables non-static:

```
public class Car {
  private static final double MILES_PER_YEAR = 20000;
  private static final double GAS_PRICE =  2.50;

  private double pricePerYear;
  private double totalPrice;

  public Car(double initialPrice, double milesPerGallon) {
    pricePerYear = (MILES_PER_YEAR / milesPerGallon);
    totalPrice = initialPrice;
  }
}
```

`static` *specifically* means that members don’t belong to one specific instance and are instead shared by all of them. This makes sense for values such as `MILES_PER_YEAR` and `GAS_PRICE`: these are always the same, regardless of what car you define.

Comment: That makes so much sense, thanks for the help.  Static is a lot more simple than I originally thought.